# Emulate a mouse

Tags: node.js, mouse, emulation

I want to emulate a mouse, that just moves around and left clicks while doing so.
I tried using RobotJS(https://www.npmjs.com/package/robotjs) but it didn't work out for me, so I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Asking for libs is off-topic. If you have specific problems with it, consider addressing them directly. Switching a lib if something didn't work isn't very productive, especially if there are no alternatives.

Comment: why hasn't `robotjs` worked ?